# Videostabilization opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

I'm trying to do videostabilize in opencv and I was wondering what a TwoPassStabilizer is?

According to [the code](http://fossies.org/dox/opencv-2.4.9/stabilizer_8cpp_source.html) the Two Pass Stabilizer does a "pre-pass" (line 310) which I notice is similar to just doing a One pass. However, after that I notice them only stabilizing the frames. Where are they re-estimating the motions after the pre-pass?